# Unknown table in where clause trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to make a trigger to update my product status. After it gets delivered. So when something is inserted in `entrega_viaturas` it triggers and updates `estado` in `viatura`.
Here are the tables and code for the trigger, please if you see something wrong, do tell.

```sql
Tabel entrega_viaturas(id_entrega,data_entrega,funcionario,viatura(fk id_viatura))
Tabel viatura(id_viatura,estado,*other columns*)

CREATE TRIGGER `Update_Status` AFTER INSERT ON `entrega_viaturas`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 AS 
begin
 update viatura
 SET estado='Indisponivel'
 Where viatura.id_viatura = entrega_viaturas.viatura  
end
```

But it says that entrega_viaturas.viaturas is a unknown column. help

Comment: Your syntax suggests MySQL, so I removed the sql-server tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, thanks for the quick fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you intend to use `new`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Update_Status` AFTER INSERT ON `entrega_viaturas`
FOR EACH ROW
AS 
begin
    update viatura
        set estado = 'Indisponivel'
        where viatura.id_viatura = new.viatura  
end;
```

Comment: What does new do ? I want to update the table `viatura` and column `estado` when an insertion happens in `entrega_viaturas`

Comment: And i was thinking that i need to compare the id's so it only changes the correct one...

Comment: @DiogoNeves . . . `new` refers to the row that is modified by the trigger.

Comment: but the row thats being modified by the trigger is on `viatura` or am i wrong ?

Comment: it is solved, FK in  `entrega_viaturas` was not id_viatura, changed it and now it works. thanks